Pywin32 open Excel file take too much time
I have a Excel file that receiver stock market data streaming real-time from excel add-in .xll
my excel file also using that data and calculate on them
if i open it manually by excel app in window  it just take 30 seconds
but when i open by pywin32 it take too much time
sometime can't open
        excel.Visible = False
        excel.DisplayAlerts = False
        excel.Calculation = win32.constants.xlCalculationManual   
        workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path)
        excel.RegisterXLL(fireant_path)
        workbook.RefreshAll()
        excel.CalculateFull()


Very suspicious behavior to any security software.  Temporarily disable it and try again.
